# How do I use the additional line breakpoint markers in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have the following line selected for a breakpoint within Chrome Dev Tools

[image: Line Breakpoint]

I don't know what the additional markers mean, nor do I know how to use them.

Do these only appear for multiple arrow functions on the same line? Is it possible to stop the code's execution on these markers? If so, how?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript you're able to just run everything on one line, as long as each line is separated by a `;` (wherever a `;` would typically be used that is).

What chrome is doing here is it's showing that you can breakpoint at those "lines" as well, all you have to do is click on the indicators to enable them.

They will appear anywhere as long as it's something that could be considered its own line.

[image]

Comment: Tried clicking on them and nothing happens. :\ But if that's what I need to do, then it's most likely a combination of user error.

Comment: @MSD that's odd, I added a gif enabling / disabling a few on some code I had readily available, couldn't tell you why you weren't able to interact with them

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer and fiddle with it some more. Thank you for your help.